# Sketchup to urdf file not found

Tags: urdf, collada

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm trying to import my robotmodel on rviz but when I change the urdf file from

to a mesh (created by sketchup) like

when i run rviz the shell tell me

> [ERROR] [1370333859.322282991]: Could not load resource [package://robo01.dae]: Unable to open file "package://robo01.dae".
> [ERROR] [1370333859.324037613]: Could not load model 'package://robo01.dae' for link 'base_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://robo01.dae in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 753)

following this post https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/mailman/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=56835&action=ListThreads&mailman_id=20

i try

> ls `rospack find urdf_tutorial`/robo01.dae

and it tell me that the file is in correct place (??).

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

thanks a lot guys for your answer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64261/sketchup-to-urdf-file-not-found/) by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @danielq,

You need to specify the actual package name and subdirectory (if any) in your URL.  So try this:

If your model was in a subdirectory of the urdf_tutorial package called "meshes" (for example), you would use:

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2013-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-06-07**:
thanks Patrick for the answer. It was soo simple soo it works.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-06-12**:
Hi @danielq.  Glad that did the trick.  Please mark the answer as "correct" by clicking the checkmark above.